# Bitstream analyzer for MPEG-4 Part 2

Tags: h.264, mpeg-4, bitstream

Why do most commercial bitstream analyzers not support MPEG-4 Part 2 (MPEG-4 Visual), i.e. codecs such as DivX and XVid? I tried out the one from [Codecian](http://www.elecard.com/en/products/professional/analysis/streameye4.html) and checked out the features of [Elecard](http://www.elecard.com/en/products/professional/analysis/streameye4.html) software. Neither of them seem to support MPEG-4 Part 2. Codecian works smoothly with Part 10 (H.264) though.

Comment: You might have better luck at a forum related to video codecs and software, like the ones at doom9.org or videohelp.com.

Comment: Yes, they look more relevant. Thanks for the guidance.